# How to make a hyperlink image within a div tag?

Tags: html, css

Iam making a website And use div tags and css to make a box around The text And images. The images are used for hyperlinks since this is a game site. But The code in The div tag doesnt work but outside The div tag it works. Please give me a code that works.

My code:

```
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;>
    <A HREF="http://www.test-joey-spellen.byethost4.com/Games/arcade.html">
        <IMG BORDER="0" SRC="images/arcade.jpeg" width="130" height="85">
    </A>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a quote at the end of the first line.

Instead of this,

```
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;>
```

Do this :

```
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;">
<a href="http://www.test-joey-spellen.byethost4.com/Games/arcade.html">
<img border="0" src="images/arcade.jpeg" width="130" height="85">
</a>
</div>
```

Your code was missing the closing double inverted commas for the "style". Also try using an external css file and include all the css in that file. And do not write HTML tags with "CAPSLOCK" on.

Answer (score 0):

you mistack in style attribute not close `quote`

Change your html

```
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;"><a href="http://www.test-joey-spellen.byethost4.com/Games/arcade.html"><img border="0" src="images/arcade.jpeg" width="130" height="85"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.are you mistake in style attribute not close quote(")

```
<a href="http://www.test-joey-spellen.byethost4.com/Games/arcade.html">
<div style="width:825px;height:300px;border:15px solid black;background-color:lightgrey;padding: 25px;margin: 25px;">
<IMG BORDER="0" SRC="images/arcade.jpeg" width="130" height="85">
</div>
</a>
```